# CSS alignment: flexbox/ tailwind alignment issues

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Currently I'm using tailwind to align data in react, I've tried adding flexbox but it appears im off with a few things

This is my expected outcome:[image]

I would love if someone can explain what im doing wrong as well.

Current outcome:
[image]

My last attempt was this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const SummaryPerPlatform = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="max-w-md overflow-hidden bg-white m-4">
        <div className="flex flex-col min-h-full">
          <div className="flex flex-col flex-grow">
            <div className="px-6 py-3 border-b">
              <div className="text-xl font-bold"> Twitter </div>
            </div>
            <div className="px-6 py-3 border-b">
              <span className="">Avg. sentigment(0.0 -1.0)</span>
              <span className="">0.31</span>
            </div>
            <div className="px-6 py-3 border-b">
              <div className="text-xl font-bold"> Instagram </div>
              <span className="">Post analyzed</span>
              <span className="">5,670</span>
            </div>
            <div className="px-6 py-3 border-b">
              <div className="text-xl font-bold"> LinkedIn </div>
              <span className="">Positive posts (>0.66)</span>
              <span className="">1,849</span>
            </div>
            <div className="px-6 py-3 border-b">
              <span className="">Negative posts (0.33)</span>
              <span className="">1,981</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SummaryPerPlatform;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<SummaryPerPlatform />, rootElement);
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flex-row` instead of `flex-col` for whole container. Otherwise I would suggest for using an extra div for differentiating these sections and using [Grid](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns/) to arrange these `div` in a similar width.

You can try like this:

```
// ...
return (
    <div>
        <div className="max-w-md overflow-hidden bg-white m-4">
            <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-1">
                <div>
                    <div className="px-6 py-3 border-b">
                        <div className="text-xl font-bold"> Twitter </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="px-6 py-3 border-b">
                        <span className="">Avg. sentigment(0.0 -1.0)</span>
                        <span className="">0.31</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className="px-6 py-3 border-b">
                        <div className="text-xl font-bold"> Instagram </div>
                        <span className="">Post analyzed</span>
                        <span className="">5,670</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className="px-6 py-3 border-b">
                        <div className="text-xl font-bold"> LinkedIn </div>
                        <span className="">Positive posts (>0.66)</span>
                        <span className="">1,849</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="px-6 py-3 border-b">
                        <span className="">Negative posts (0.33)</span>
                        <span className="">1,981</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
// ...
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. why would flex-col be better ? can you provide a fiddle or sandbox example